# Download/submission directories are dead? Are they good for SEO?

Tags: seo, backlinks, link-submission

We have just released a new major software product version.

In the past if you wanted visibility you would create a standardized pad file and you would submit it to hundreds of directories or you used web service that would do that for you. 
These directories would then serve as first incoming links to your web site.

How about today? I think download directories are pretty much dead?
Do you think this is still good SEO approach today? Are these software download directories useless?

Comment: This is just personal experience, but those download sites still exist in abundance. Almost every piece of ISV software I've ever used or purchased by googling came from one of the directory sites. That said, a lot of them are horrible to use and deceptive in the way they advertise, so buyer beware.

Answer (score 1):

I think script directories and the like are still quite popular, although these days most people are using the extensions on their CMS (Wordpress, Joomla etc) for the majority of "additional functionality".

I have a couple of PHP scripts that I listed on HotScripts.com years ago and to this day I still get a significant amount of traffic from there. So go ahead and spread the word - if your software is fantastic you won't need to do too much self-promotion before others are doing the promoting for you!

Answer (score 0):

Not dead, not as good as in the past. Worths the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem if you use XML pad files to submit your software is the duplicate content. The same description of your product is on several websites and search engine does not like that too much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, submitting your website is good for SEO.  However, doing so will not take effect immediately.  It will take quite a bit of time to get the results you want.

I know this because I have done many submissions to articles, directories, search engine.  I finally got the good results I was looking for.

Comment: What makes you think it's good for SEO?

Comment: If you got good rankings after a significant time period, how do you know it was submitting to directories that helped?     If you submitted to spammy directories or commented in spammy ways on articles, your efforts are also likely to penalize your site at some point.